# How do modern operating systems handle processes with runaway memory leaks?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, operating-system, out-of-memory

If I write a program like the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  while (1)
    malloc(100);
}
```

and I run `gcc a.c && ./a.out`, how bad will things get?

Will the operating system allow other processes to get choked out? Would it be different if I ran `sudo ./a.out`?

I am hoping that there is some best practices that most modern operating systems follow, but if there isn't I would be happy with an answer specifically for OS X to reduce scope.

Comment: There's a concept on Unix called [ulimit](https://www.google.com/search?q=ulimit). I don't understand the details so I can't say any more.

Comment: Assuming the compiler doesn't optimise your loop out completely you'll normally hit some OS defined per process limit and malloc with return 0 (ok since you aren't dereferencing it).

Comment: In linux kernel there is an oom (out of memory) killer. Every process gets `oom_score` and can be adjusted via `oom_adj`. In cases where `ulimit` allows huge memory allocation such as a DB server and processes running  have the same ulimit as this DB, then oom killer will be at work, unless you disable it. Unfortunately, I don't have any clue what darwin kernel has.